# Using custom protocol

Tags: c#, flurl

I would like to use another protocol than `http(s)://` in particular i want to build a URL that begins with `vrchat://` but for some reason it always kills the second `/`

```
        var url = "vrchat://".AppendPathSegment("launch");
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(innerString)) {
            url.SetQueryParam("id", innerString, true);
        }
        //url.SetQueryParam("ref", "vrchat.com");
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to {0}", url);
```

Results in

```
Connecting to vrchat:/launch?id=wrld_b805006c-bec7-4179-958a-5a9351e48d5c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually appending a path segment there, you're appending an [authority](http://uri.thephpleague.com/4.0/components/overview/). The main behaviors of `AppendPathSegment` over plain old string concatenation are encoding and ensuring 1 and only 1 `/` character between segments, which is most likely causing what you're seeing. You don't want or need those behaviors here, so (assuming authority is variable) just use string concatenation:

```
var url = "vrchat://" + authority;
// or
var url = $"vrchat://{authority}";
```